# how to automatically build and refresh spring mvc project using intellij like devtools in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, build

for each change in my project I have to use clean install to generate my war then launch the tomcat server to run my project

How can i generate my war automatically like using dev tools in spring boot ?

Comment: Use exploded artifact built by IntelliJ IDEA, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Comment: thank you @CrazyCoder I will try it